# Geometry and linear equation systems

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

> For a number $a\in\mathbb{R}$ in a $(x,y,z)$-coordinate system in three-dimensional space, 4 planes $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4$ are given:
>   $$\alpha_1:x+ay+a^2z=a^3$$
>   $$\alpha_2:ay+(a-a^2)z=0$$
>   $$\alpha_3:-x-a^2z=-a$$
>   $$\alpha_4:x+2ay+az=a$$
>   It is stated that there exists a value of $a$ where the 4 planes have exactly one common point, and a value of $a$ where the union set of points in the 4 planes is a straight line.

---

I'm stuck trying to find these two values. I tried solving it as a system of linear equations, but I end up with an inconsistent system and therefore no solution. Any hints?

Comment: Normal row reduction should work fine - maybe you made calculation error(s)?

Comment: In the process of row-reducing the matrix, did you find yourself dividing by something like $a^2-1$?  If so, you implicitly assumed that $a$ was neither $1$ nor $-1$, so you would need to try these values separately.  Similarly, if you divided by $a$ at some point, you need to try the value $a=0$ separately.

Comment: I checked with Maple and it said the same. Hmm.

Comment: @AustinChristian I multiplied row 2 by $a^{-1}$. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @Steve Yes.  When you multiply by $a^{-1}$, you're assuming that $a\neq 0$.  But when $a=0$, the plane $x=0$ satisfies all four equations.  I would also investigate the cases where $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: @AustinChristian can I assume that $a\neq0$ since if you set a equal to 0 to begin with, it's an unsolvable equation?

Comment: I don't follow.  If we set $a=0$, then the four equations become $x=0$, $0=0$, $0=0$, and $x=0$, which are all solved by any point in the $yz$-plane.  As mentioned, though, I think you should look into the cases where $a=\pm 1$.  Make sure you're not cancelling any $a+1$ or $a-1$ terms when you do your row reduction.